# How to extract unique rows from a data frame with an index column?

Tags: r, excel, unique

I'm importing from Excel to R, not duplicates and a row number of Excel (Index). If I do the unique() before setting up Index, the position of the rows in the data frame won't correspond to the Excel file. If I do unique() after Index, it will take into account also the Index column, and there won't be any duplicates.

This:

```
Index   a   b   c
1       12  12  14
2       12  12  14
3       11  12  13
```

to this:

```
Index   a   b   c
1       12  12  14
3       11  12  13
```

Code:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
dati <- data.table(read.xlsx("\\\\192.168.x.x\\file.xlsx", detectDates = TRUE))
#Index row
dati <- tibble::rowid_to_column(dati, "Index")
```

(If it's a repeated question I apologize, I searched high and low for days and couldn't find anything. I have a feeling it's a very simple solution under a different keyword)

Comment: Try `i <- duplicated(df[-1]); df[!i, ]`. Maybe the other way around is more readable, negate `duplicated`, not the index `i` when subsetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `duplicated()`.

```
> df1[-which(duplicated(df1[,-1])), ]
  Index  a  b  c
1     1 12 12 14
3     3 11 12 13
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(Index = 1:3, a = c(12L, 12L, 11L), b = c(12L, 
                                                               12L, 12L), c = c(14L, 14L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                     -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to understand the logic behind this code: -which() means 'which is not'? while the -1 of df1[,-1] means exclude the 1st column?

Comment: Close, `which()` gives you indices (row numbers), the `-` excludes the specified rows (left side of comma within brackets). The negation "is not" would be `!`, if you prefere this you could do `df1[which(!duplicated(df1[,-1])), ]`.